# Vibrating circular membrane: why is there a singularity at r = 0 using polar coordinates?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation, singularity

When solving the partial differential equations for a vibrating circular membrane:

PDE:

$$\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2} = c^2\nabla^2u$$

Subject to the following boundary coundtion:

$$u(a, \theta, t) = 0$$

Why is there a singularity at $$r = 0$$?

Comment: isn't there always a singularity in polar coordinates at $r=0$? it is only a diffeomorphism of the punctured plane.

Comment: Can you please explain why this is so? or can you please provide a link that explains the singularity?

Comment: Because at the origin $r=0$ and $\theta$ can be anything: The map $(r,\theta)\mapsto (r\cos \theta,r\sin\theta)$ has nontrivial kernel (lots of things map to $(0,0)$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The singularity occurs because the Jacobian of the coordinate transformation from polar to rectangular is $r$, which vanishes at $r=0$. So it is an artifact of the non-faithful coordinate transformation.

For an orthogonal coordinate transformation in $3d$ from $(a,b,c)$ to $(x,y,z)$ with metric scale factors $m_a,m_b,m_c$, the Laplacian becomes
$$
    \Delta f=  \frac{1}{m_a m_b m_c}\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial a}\left(\frac{m_b m_c}{m_a}\frac{\partial f}{\partial a}\right)+\frac{\partial }{\partial b}\left(\frac{m_a m_c}{m_b}\frac{\partial f}{\partial{b}}\right)+\frac{\partial  f}{\partial c}\left(\frac{m_a m_b}{m_c}\frac{\partial f }{\partial c}\right)\right]
$$
The Jacobian of such an orthogonal coordinate transformation is $J=m_am_bm_c$.
There is a singularity at any point where one or more of the  metric scale factors $m_a,m_b,m_c$ vanish.

For example, cylindrical coordinates is an orthogonal coordinate system in variables $r,\theta,z$, the scale factors are $m_r=1,m_{\theta}=r,m_z=1$. The Laplacian in cylindrical coordinates is
\begin{align}
      \Delta f & = \frac{1}{r}\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}\right)+\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\left(\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta}\right)+\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\left(r\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\right)\right] \\
   & =\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}\right)+\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial \theta^2}+\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial z^2}.
\end{align}
If you leave out the $z$ dependence, there is a reduction to polar coordinates. There is a singularity at $r=0$ because the Jacobian $J=r$ vanishes at $r=0$. This allows a non-trivial singular solution $f(r,\theta,\phi)=\ln(r)$, which is a multiple of the so-called "fundamental" solution. This solution does not naturally arise in Cartesian coordinates, but does in cylindrical coordinates. In order to eliminate such a solution, a condition must be imposed at $r=0$, such as requiring boundedness of $f$ near $r=0$, which turns out to be the correct condition for eliminating the fundamental solution.

Comment: nice answer,+1. I like the connection to the fundamental solution.